# Strongswan cannot authenticate with FreeRADIUS server: DNS error

Tags: centos, vpn, radius, strongswan

I'm trying to set up RADIUS auth with my Strongswan server.

I get the following error:

```
Jun  2 20:51:47 nl1 charon: 17[LIB] resolving 'radius.server.com' failed: Name or service not known
Jun  2 20:51:47 nl1 charon: 14[IKE] initiating EAP_RADIUS method failed
Jun  2 20:51:47 nl1 charon: 14[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 2 [ EAP/FAIL ]
```

It says it cannot resolve the hostname "radius.server.com", however when I ping or DIG the hostname on my server it works fine. resolv.conf is also set correctly.

How does Strongswan resolve the RADIUS hostname and how can I fix this ? When I enter the IP directly it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It uses `getaddrinfo()` to resolve the hostname ("`Name or service not known`" is actually an error message returned by `gai_strerror()`).

So if this doesn't work, either the configured hostname isn't correct or the resolver isn't set up correctly somehow.

Comment: I just tried calling that method from a C program I wrote and it resolves the domain perfectly. Meanwhile the error is still being thrown in Strongswan. Does strongswan use any specific resolver settings for this ?

Comment: It sets `ai_family` (to `AF_UNSPEC` in this case) and `ai_socktype` (to `SOCK_DGRAM`) in `struct addrinfo` passed to `getaddrinfo()` (`NULL` is passed as second argument/`service`). As far as I know, there are no application-specific resolver settings (unless perhaps you link applications to differently configured C libraries, or via namespaces/chroots).